# Jcarousel basic, make it responsive

Tags: jcarousel, responsive-slides

i have a jcarousel slider on my webpage, the basic version ( the one with only one image display ), i can't seems to resize with media queries the div the jcarousel slider.

Here is the HTML CODE

```
<div id="mycarousel">
<div class="wrapper">


<div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
<div class="jcarousel">
<ul>
<li><img src="img/macu/slide1.png" width="700" height="500" alt=""></li>


<li><img src="img/macu/slide5.png" width="700" height="500" alt=""></li>

</ul>
/div>

<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev"></a> 
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next"></a>

<!--
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a> 
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>
-->
<!--  <p class="jcarousel-pagination"> -->
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is my css

```
@media screen and (max-width:545px){
//body {background:orange;}
#content {
width:43%;
height:auto;
}

#media,#vignette {
width:auto;
height:auto;

}
#menu {
width:32%;
font-size:80%;
}

.jcarousel{
width:22%;
//font-size:80%;
}

}
```

here is the js

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();







    $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        })
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
        })
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

    $('.jcarousel-control-next')
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        })
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
        })
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=1'
        });

    $('.jcarousel-pagination')
        .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })
        .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        .jcarouselPagination();
});





})(jQuery);
```

Do i have to change anything in the js ? i find out there is a responsive jcarousel but it show 3 pictures at the same time ...
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/responsive/

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also display a different number of items depending on the container size.

```
$('.jcarousel')
.on('jcarousel:create jcarousel:reload', function() {
    var element = $(this),
        width = element.innerWidth();

    if (width > 900) {
        width = width / 3;
    } else if (width > 600) {
        width = width / 2;
    }

    element.jcarousel('items').css('width', width + 'px');
})
.jcarousel({
    // Your configurations options
});
```

so if you want show more than 3 pictures you just change for width/4